# Regex - Find numbers between 2000 and 3000

Tags: regex

I have a need to search all numbers with 4 digits between 2000 and 3000.

It can be that letters are before and after.

I thought I can use `[2000-3000]{4}`, but doesnt work, why?

thank you.

Comment: Instead of explaining why this doesn't work, I ask you: How exactly do you expect this to work? And which regex rule do you expect to trigger that behaviour?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about

```
^2\d{3}|3000$
```

Or as Amarghosh & Bart K. & jleedev pointed out, to match multiple instances

```
\b(?:2[0-9]{3}|3000)\b
```

If you need to match `a3000` or `3000a` but not `13000`, you would need lookahead and lookbefore like

```
(?<![0-9])(?:2[0-9]{3}|3000)(?![0-9])
```

Comment: +1 though I think start/end markers are not really required since we're going to capture all numbers.

Comment: Is `\d` guaranteed to match just `[0-9]` or does it depend on the locale?

Comment: `12000` shouldn't match as `2000`, isn't it?

Comment: Add a word boundary `\b` instead of `^` and `$` @S.Mark Did you make it CW to stay on 10K for ever?

Comment: That matches `13000` too (or `a3000`). It mathces `^2\d{3}` or `3000$`: you need to add some parenthesis.

Comment: @Amarghosh, for today at least. :D

Comment: @S.Mark Apparently you are safe for the day anyway - I tried to spoil your plans by up-voting on another post but you seem to have hit the rep-cap ;) You'd get a nice answer badge though.

Comment: now I changed to (?:3[0-9]{3}|10000), to get all between 3000  and 10000, it won't find 4000.

Comment: it would be `(?:[3-9][0-9]{3}|10000)`

Comment: @S.Mark, from the question "It can be that letters are before and after"

Comment: it works for my solution now, but I had to remove the ?: what does it mean "?:" ?, Thank you all.

Comment: @snarebold `?:` makes a parenthetical group non capturing. Consider the string `"abbbcccd"` and regexes `a(b+)(c+)d` and `a(?:b+)(c+)d`. The matched results of first regex will contain `bbb` in first group and `ccc` in second group. Results of second regex will contain `ccc` in its first (and only) group as `(b+)` group was made non-capturing using `?:` See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for more info.

Comment: Please take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x(VS.85).aspx and search for `(?:pattern)`

Answer (score 9):

Regular expressions are rarely suitable for checking ranges since for ranges like 27 through 9076 inclusive, they become incredibly ugly. It *can* be done but you're really better off just doing a regex to check for numerics, something like:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

which should work on just about *every* regex engine, and then check the range manually.

In toto:

```
def isBetween2kAnd3k(s):
    if not s.match ("^[0-9]+$"):
        return false
    i = s.toInt()
    if i < 2000 or i > 3000:
        return false
    return true
```

What *your* particular regex `[2000-3000]{4}` is checking for is exactly four occurrences of any of the following character: `2,0,0,0-3,0,0,0` - in other words, exactly four digits drawn from `0-3`.

With letters before an after, you will need to modify the regex and check the correct substring, something like:

```
def isBetween2kAnd3kWithLetters(s):
    if not s.match ("^[A-Za-z]*[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]*$"):
        return false
    idx = s.locate ("[0-9]")
    i = s.substring(idx,4).toInt()
    if i < 2000 or i > 3000:
        return false
    return true
```

---

As an aside, a regex for checking the range 27 through 9076 inclusive would be something like this hideous monstrosity:

```
^2[7-9]|[3-9][9-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-8][0-9]{3}|90[0-6][0-9]|907[0-6]$
```

I think that's substantially less readable than using `^[1-9][0-9]+$` then checking if it's between 27 and 9076 with an `if` statement?

Answer (score 3):

Hum tricky one. The dash - only applies to the character immediately before and after so what your regex is actually matching is exactly 4 characters between 0 and 3 inclusive (ie, 0, 1, 2 and 3). eg, 3210, 1230, 3333, etc... Try the expression below.

`(2[0-9]{3})|(3000)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's explanation why and ways to detect ranges: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 2):

Correct regex will be `\b(2\d{3}|3000)\b`. That means: match character '2' then exactly three digits (this will match any from 2000 to 2999) or just match '3000'. There are some good tutorials on regular expressions:

1. http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html
2. http://immike.net/blog/2007/04/06/the-absolute-bare-minimum-every-programmer-should-know-about-regular-expressions/
3. http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

why don't you check for greater or less than? its simpler than a regex

```
num >= 2000 and num <=3000
```